# Should we be notified when an edit has been made to an answer we have recieved?

Tags: feature-request

Once I asked a question. I recieved an answer but didn't like it entirely. I offered a bounty. The days went and I recieved no answer. One day I happened to go to the question and the previous answer had been substantially improved and I hadn't been notified.

I believe that  notifying askers when an answer has been modified might be useful.

Of course, this has the downside that every little edit ( gramatical mistakes for example) might be annoying.

Nonetheless, this could be easily solved giving to the one who makes the edit the possibility to decide whether or not it is worthy notifying the edit to the asker.

What do you think?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at the main Meta site, not on the Physics Meta site

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative way to accomplish this is to simply [mark your questions as Favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work). In that way, they will come up on the Favorites > activity tab on your profile when they are edited. The people who want this information can then access it, and everyone else is left *without* a bunch of annoying notifications, and particularly so the [people with many tens of questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/44871/top-question-askers).

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly be helpful if the one who gives an answer has the ability to make the edit significant enough to be notified the asker. Informing about the edits to the answer cannot be dropped of course, because it can lead to loads of misinformation. A simple typo of leaving out 'not' can significantly change the meaning of the answer.

Comment: I've seen Wiki-software with a checkbox "this is a minor edit". Give the editer the change to uncheck it. That would solve the issue.